# Using window.openDatabase with Typescript in PhpStorm project

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, web-sql

When creating a new (empty) PhpStorm project I chose TypeScript as my script language since I'm familiar with OOP concepts and I like them.

When accessing the WebSQL service with JS I can code

```
var db = window.openDataBase(name, version, displayName, size)
```

But there is a problem when doing this with typescript. TS doesn't know the property `openDatabase` for what ever reason.

I already read a few posts and they all came out to be a problem belonging to Cordova/PhoneGap. Since I just want to make a simple WebApp, which checks if the local store has data, then display data and if not get the data from the server, this would be too much and. As I said this should just be a webpage the user accesses and can add to his/her homescreen. Nothing more.

The "good old" WebSQL would be perfect for me, since my target devices are Android and iOS which are both supporting WebSQL. The question is how do I get access to openDatabase using TS??

I read about the SQLite plugin from Cordova which I installed via NPM. But there I had to give a database name. That fact has concerned me for platform compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 10):

Installing `websql` typings (`npm i @types/websql`) should help:

[image]